# How to extract name of objects from technical description (NLP)

Tags: nlp

I have a list of technical descriptions of mechanical parts such as

Relay Compressor A4u8skk

Relay-Start-Compressor sdfvsh2

Relay-Start-Compressor-Copelan 05-569-21

Compressor-J4KS0AK-5gss-fj2

and i would like that my model output for the each sample of that list above will be "Compressor" , i have 700+ unique samples like the one above, not only Compressor but large list of items .

What is the best approach / models that i should look for that kind of task? 
is topic modeling related ?

Comment: A very simple approach could be to first extract all the words from this text using regex and then selecting the one with maximum frequency.

Comment: But there are hundreds samples in my list and X unknown  amount of unique mechanical parts. I would like that even item such as "screw" that appear only in 4 description samples will get its label.